# How to use KAFKA's producer API in librdkafka with c++ code on windows

Tags: c++, apache-kafka, producer

I am trying to write a client as an producer.
I followed examples to create a new win32 console project.
I found the API doesn't work for me unless I add getline() function at the end of my program.

If I remove the getline(), the produce(..) method still returns the result of success. 
However, I cannot see any response in the command window of kafka-console-consumer

I got a little bit confused. Is that right?
How can I send message without using getline()?
Anyone knows?

I found why it doesn't work.
It seems too fast to delete the producer object
causing the producer cannot send messages to broker.

When I add sleep 1000 between produce method and delete producer object,
producer can send message correctly.

So, the question is How to send message immediately.
How can I make sure those message have been send totally before I destroy the producer object?

How to fix this problem, actually I don't like to add some sleep() in my source code.

win10+vs2015+kafka_2.10-0.9.0.1+zookeeper-3.4.6+librdkafka
Please check out the following code

```
    // kafka_test_win32_nomfc.cpp 
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "librdkafka/rdkafkacpp.h"


int static producer_1()
{
    std::string brokers = "127.0.0.1";
    std::string errstr;
    std::string topic_str = "linli";
    std::string mode;
    std::string debug;
    int32_t partition = RdKafka::Topic::PARTITION_UA;
    int64_t start_offset = RdKafka::Topic::OFFSET_BEGINNING;
    bool do_conf_dump = false;
    int opt;
    // MyHashPartitionerCb hash_partitioner;
    int use_ccb = 0;

    /*
    * Create configuration objects
    */
    RdKafka::Conf *conf = RdKafka::Conf::create(RdKafka::Conf::CONF_GLOBAL);
    RdKafka::Conf *tconf = RdKafka::Conf::create(RdKafka::Conf::CONF_TOPIC);

    conf->set("metadata.broker.list", brokers, errstr);

    RdKafka::Producer *producer = RdKafka::Producer::create(conf, errstr);
    if (!producer) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create producer: " << errstr << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    std::cout << "% Created producer " << producer->name() << std::endl;

    /*
    * Create topic handle.
    */
    RdKafka::Topic *topic = NULL;
    if (!topic_str.empty()) {
        topic = RdKafka::Topic::create(producer, topic_str, tconf, errstr);
        if (!topic) {
            std::cerr << "Failed to create topic: " << errstr << std::endl;
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    RdKafka::ErrorCode resp = producer->produce(topic, partition,
        RdKafka::Producer::RK_MSG_COPY /* Copy payload */,
        const_cast<char *>("hello worlf"), 11,
        NULL, NULL);

    delete topic;
    delete producer;
    return 0;
}


int static producer_2()
{
    std::string brokers = "127.0.0.1";
    std::string errstr;
    std::string topic_str = "linli";
    std::string mode;
    std::string debug;
    int32_t partition = RdKafka::Topic::PARTITION_UA;
    int64_t start_offset = RdKafka::Topic::OFFSET_BEGINNING;
    bool do_conf_dump = false;
    int opt;
    // MyHashPartitionerCb hash_partitioner;
    int use_ccb = 0;

    RdKafka::Conf *conf = RdKafka::Conf::create(RdKafka::Conf::CONF_GLOBAL);
    RdKafka::Conf *tconf = RdKafka::Conf::create(RdKafka::Conf::CONF_TOPIC);

    conf->set("metadata.broker.list", brokers, errstr);

    RdKafka::Producer *producer = RdKafka::Producer::create(conf, errstr);
    if (!producer) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create producer: " << errstr << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    std::cout << "% Created producer " << producer->name() << std::endl;

    RdKafka::ErrorCode resp = producer->produce(topic_str, partition,
        RdKafka::Producer::RK_MSG_COPY /* Copy payload */,
        (void *)"hi", 2,
        NULL, 0, 0, NULL);



    std::string errs(RdKafka::err2str(resp));
    std::cout << errs << std::endl;
    //producer->poll(0);


    delete producer;

    return 0;
}


int main()
{

    producer_2();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The librdkafka produce() API (both C and C++) is asynchronous, your message will initially only be enqueued on the internal producer queue and only later (see the `queue.buffering.max.ms` configuration property - default 1 second) be combined with other messages into a message batch (MessageSet) and sent to the broker from a background thread.

Your program calls `produce()` and then quickly exits, long before the background producer thread has had a chance to send the message to the broker, much less receive an acknowledgement from the broker.

To make sure all outstanding messages have been sent, call `flush()`, before terminating your application.

If your application is long-lived you should call `poll()` at regular intervals to serve any delivery report callbacks you've registered.

Comment: Thank you for your replay.  Actually, I want to integrate producer into an multi-thread socket server application. I am ready to put the producer object into the socket work-thread, so the producer is not work at a long-lived thread. In another way, I have tried flush() method you mentioned, I add it between produce method and the delete method, but the kafka-console-consumer still cannot have any acknowledgement. That proves flush() cannot make sure your messages are sent before the the application’s termination.

Comment: If the producer has to be in a long-life thread, the integration will become much complex because I have to write a new thread pool to manage the producer threads. Is there any better solutions?

Comment: librdkafka is thread-safe, you can (and should) use the same Producer instance from multiple application threads. What you typically do is let any app thread call produce(), and create a separate app thread (or use the main thread's loop) to poll() to serve delivery reports and other callbacks.

Comment: I will test it to see whether the singleton producer can be an I/O bottle-neck or not.